# Environment NewLine Not Working In Text File

Tags: vb.net

I am instantiating a StringBuilder and trying to write to a text file. My code writes to the text file fine but the StringBuilder is not creating carriage returns for me.

Ive tried..

- Environment.NewLine
- \n
- .AppendLine()

and nothing seems to work with the StringBuilder object

Here is some code I am using to create the string that gets inserted into the flat file

'ErrorLog is a new StringBuilder object

```
_mErrInfo.ErrorLog.Append("Start Validiting Detail....." + Environment.NewLine)
```

Comment: \n is newline, \r is carriage return. But I don't think VB understands those escapes. You could manually write chr(13) and chr(10) bytes or the vbCrLf constant. In Windows, text files expect both characters.

Comment: Concatenating `Environment.NewLine`, like that, will work fine.  Calling `AppendLine` would be better.  As @mafafu said, `\n` does not work in VB.NET.  The problem is not the `StringBuilder`.  The problem must be somewhere else such as where you are outputting the contents of the `StringBuilder` to the text file.

Comment: Please show the code where you actually write to the file.  Appending `Environment.NewLine` does work with StringBuilder as well as the `AppendLine`.  I've used both many times.  The problem must lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using StreamWriter's WriteLine Method.  Here is the MSDN reference with description.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing append to appendline like this:

```
_mErrInfo.ErrorLog.AppendLine("Start Validiting Detail.....")
```

I would also try:

```
_mErrInfo.ErrorLog.Append(vbCrLf)
```

Or change the whole line to be:

```
_mErrInfo.ErrorLog.Append("Start Validiting Detail....." & vbCrLf)
```

Or try:

```
_mErrInfo.ErrorLog.AppendLine("<br />")
```

Comment: Just added a new one please try that.

Answer (score 0):

AppendLine is the way to go.

For example:

```
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
sb.AppendLine("Start Validating Detail.....")

For i = 0 To 10
  sb.AppendLine(i)
Next

Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter("log.txt")
  sw.Write(sb.ToString)
End Using
```

Output:

Start Validating Detail.....
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work for you

```
    Dim crlf As String = Convert.ToChar(10) & Convert.ToChar(13)
    _mErrInfo.ErrorLog.Append("Start Validating Detail....." + crlf)
```